# Is it possible to use in C#/SQL Server a table variable as a parameter for stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm aware that I can use a table value parameter as another option and I was already able to implement it. The reason I'm trying to use this approach(Table variable not Table value) is because I'm studying and I want to learn other ways on how to insert to database through a stored procedure.

Here's the current query I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TVar
(
DECLARE @TblVar TABLE
(Product nvarchar(max), Qty int)

)
AS
Insert Into sample_tbl Select * FROM @TblVar
```

Is it possible to have this kind of approach wherein in the C# code I will use a datatable to pass as a parameter which can be done when using a table value parameter. I'm having errors when execute the query .

Here's the error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use a table value parameter as a parameter to a stored procedure, and you can call from C#.

You need to separately declare a `TABLE` `TYPE`:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE 
(
    Product nvarchar(max),
    Qty int
);
GO
```

and then use like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TVar   
(   
   @TblVar as dbo.MyTableType READONLY  
)   
AS  
...
```

These articles show how to build a .NET `DataTable` to call the stored procedure from C#:

- [C# and Table Value Parameters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters)
- [Table Value Parameters in SQL Server 2008 and .NET (C#)](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/)

Comment: I was already able to implement using a table value, I'm actually trying to have a table variable as a parameter and use a datatable in the C# code for the parameter. Thank you though for the immediate response.

Comment: your comment doesn't seem to match what you said in your question? Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: @MitchWheat would this be a possible solution for moving data in the other direction e.g. the stored proc results in an OUTPUT TVP and then this data goes into a C# DataTable and then that table is emptied into say Excel?